# Sort coredata on the basis of price

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

I have an attribute called `offerPrice` in coredata of `String` type. Now on the click of a button I want to sort all elements in the coredata array on the basis of this offerprice in ascending order.

I could sort on the basis of `names` like so...

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NewProduct")

let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

do {
    newProdDetails2 = try context.fetch(request) as! [NewProduct]
    tableview.reloadData()
   } catch {
      print("Fetching Failed")
 }
```

In this place, `key: "name"` I tried giving `offerPrice` instead of `name` to sort on the basis of `offerPrice`. But it doesn't work..

Comment: It probably doesn't work because strings are sorted lexicographically rather than numerically. ie "9" is greater than "10".  You should store prices as numbers, not strings.

Comment: What is the order you get? Is it because you have values like "9.2" and "11.3"? That's seems plausible. Why not storing Float/Double/Int (numbers) instead?

Comment: I can sort numbers as `Int` format in ascending or desc. order. But I wanted to sort in  string format only as is the case now..

Comment: @Larme the order is random..

Comment: It should’t be random. It might have a logic that you don’t see. Could you print the prices as you get it?

Comment: @Larme The `offerprice` I mentioned come into existence when I create 'products' in the app. The offerprices thus corresponds to each products. So the offerprices are as I give for each product. So in that case, there cannot be a specified order for the `offerPrices`

Comment: Maybe you should sort your datasource array (`newProductDetails2`?) when needed rather than executing a fetch request whenever you want to sort.